# How to apply (or filter) multi level selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the snippet below. Why am I not able to select only `women` and `red` from the elements? As you can see I am trying to get only `women` and `red` boxes from the `data-color="red" data-gender="women"`.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background', $(this).data("color"));
  $(this).text($(this).data("gender"))
});
 $("a[data-gender=women],a[data-color=red] ").removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
```

```css
.zoomOut{
display:none;


}
.zoomIn{
display:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="s" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="yellow" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="black" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="khaki" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="grey" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by select? How you want to select it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that done like this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  if(this.attr('data-color') == 'red' && this.attr('data-gender') == 'women')
  {
    this.removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
  }
});
```

Comment: Here in my answer, you can do whatever you want inside `IF` condition as it will only pass the `<a>` tags which have `color=red` and `gender=women`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple attribute filter, then you need to declare the element only once.

> $("a[data-gender=women][data-color=red]")

Find the working solution below.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background', $(this).data("color"));
  $(this).text($(this).data("gender"))
});
 $("a[data-gender=women][data-color=red] ").removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
```

```css
.zoomOut{
display:none;


}
.zoomIn{
display:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="s" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="yellow" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="black" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="khaki" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="grey" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

problem was your selector

> $("a[data-gender=women],a[data-color=red] ")

which is wrong, if you want to filter by multiple attributes then there is no need to use "," or repeat tag it self just use multiple pairs of [] without "," separate.

check [this link](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) for more info

replace with this.

```
 $("a[data-gender='women'][data-color='red']")
```

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background', $(this).data("color"));
  $(this).text($(this).data("gender"))
});

$("a[data-gender='women'][data-color='red']").removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
```

```css
.zoomOut{
  display:none;
}
.zoomIn{
  display:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="s" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="yellow" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="black" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="khaki" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="grey" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
```